# Sass: Multiple class selector from a variable

Tags: css, haml, sass

I want to create a variable with classes like so

```
$multi: foo, bar, baz
```

And I want to created a combined selector like so:

```
.foo, .bar, .baz {}
```

I am used the indented syntax (don't know if that would matter). The reason I want the combined selector generated from the variable: I need to do calculations based on how many classes are defined there. Please don't give a suggestion like (use extends!) because that will require me to make another class. I need to be able to get close or exactly to the regular combined selector output.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you specified what "calculations" you need to do. Please explain why you need "to get close or exactly to the regular combined selector output"

Comment: The classes are for sprites.... so I have a sprite which has a foo, bar, and baz part of an image. I have a loop that set's the first class to a specific background, and then the last loop continues where the first left off and basically sequentially handles spriting without having to manually manage it. Right now I'm having to define the variable setup, and then manually specify the combined selectors, just because Sass won't let me do what I want to do.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue as the OP, and this was the first search result I found, so now that I’ve figured it out, I’ll post my solution, even though the question is 1.5 years old.

Here’s what I found out: in order to use a variable as a selector, you use SASS [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_), which works perfectly with comma-separated strings. However, if you want the variable that holds your selectors to be a `list` (so that you can use list functions on it, e.g.  `length($multi)`), the interpolation will generate a malformed selector.

So, the simple solution is to first define your variable as a list, then when you need to use it as a selector, convert that list into a comma-separated string:

```js
$multi: ".foo", ".bar", ".baz"
$multi-selector: ""
@each $selector in $multi
    @if $multi-selector != ""
        $multi-selector: $multi-selector + ", "
    $multi-selector: $multi-selector + $selector

#{$multi-selector}
    //CSS properties go here
```

You may want to abstract the list-to-comma-separated-string functionality into a function (note: SASS’s [`join`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#join-instance_method) function doesn’t do this; it joins two lists into a new one). Here’s one possible implementation:

```js
@function unite($list, $glue: ", ")
    @if length($list) == 1
        @return $list

    $string: ""
    @each $item in $list
        @if $string != ""
            $string: $string + $glue
        $string: $string + $item
    @return $string
```

At which point the original code can be as concise as:

```js
$multi: ".foo", ".bar", ".baz"

#{unite($multi)}
    //CSS properties go here
```

Comment: I'm sorry for editing your answer, I thought it will make a copy of yours answer with my changes. So please deny the changes, because I've cut first part of your answer which is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

(code from previous answer) Cool function! Usefull. I just wanted to add some SCSS syntax, to give an opportunity to people to use it:

```js
@function unite($list, $glue: ", ") {
     @if length($list) == 1 {
             @return $list;
     } @else {
        $string: "";
        @each $item in $list {
             @if $string != "" { $string: $string + $glue; }
                 $string: $string + $item;
     }

     @return $string;
     }
}
```

At which point the original code can be as concise as:

```js
$multi: ".foo", ".bar", ".baz"

#{unite($multi)}
    //CSS properties go here
```

Answer (score 0):

[Compass offers a built-in sprite mixin that does just this.](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) If you don't want to use all of Compass, you could [look into their source](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass) to see how they are doing it.

Comment: I find sass never allows one to do anything easily unless it is the dead simple basics.